# I need to get the index from a Html.listbox parsed to the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller, listbox

So I'm trying to get the index from the selected item from a html.listbox into the controller. I'm getting the items from a model.

The Html Code:

```
        <form id="form1">
        <div>
             <select id="s1" class="timeline" size="20" name="Options">
                    @foreach (var C in Model)
                    {
                        <option>@C.PostID.ToString(), @C.Message.Title, @C.Likes.ToString(), @C.Reports.ToString()</option>
                    }
             </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="grid_1 push_4">
        @Html.ActionLink("Filter Posts", "TimelinePage", "TimelinePage", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btnOpmaak" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_1 push_9">
        <div class="marginsforbuttonstimeline">
            <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("btnSelectPost", "TimelinePageController"))
                    {
                        <input type="submit" value="Like" onclick="Getindex()" class="btn btn-primary btnOpmaak1" />
                        @Html.Hidden("Index", null)
                        <input id="Index" name="Index" type="hidden" value= "setMyValue()" />
                    }                       
                </div>
            </form>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getSelectedItems(){
var items = "";
var frm = document.forms[0].s1;
var len = frm.length;
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(frm[i].selected){
        items += frm[i].value + "";
    }
}
return items;
}

function post()
{
    document.getElementById('contrib').value = getSelectedItems();
}

function Getindex() {
    var x = document.getElementById("s1").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("s1").options;
    var z = y[x].index;
    setMyValue(z);
}

function setMyValue(value) {
    $(document.getElementById("Index")).val(value);
    var Q = $(document.getElementById("Index"));
    return alert(JSON.stringify(Q));
}
```

The Controller:

```
    public ActionResult SetEvent(Event Event) //test
    {
        this.Event = Event;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult btnGetPost()
    {
        Event.GetContributions();
        return View("TimelinePage", Event);
    }

    public ActionResult btnSelectpost(int contrib)
    {           
        return View(contrib);
    }
```

Any Directions would be great!